# Animation on uiview

Tags: ios, animation, uiview

i have created an UIView programmatically. Now i want to disply the view with animation on. my code is below. Note that the code is on button click event.

```
 view1 = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 284)];
view1.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];
[self.view addSubview: view1];
UIButton *cancel = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
cancel.frame = CGRectMake(265, 0, 55, 20);
[cancel setTitle: @"Cancel" forState: UIControlStateNormal];
[cancel addTarget:self action:@selector(cancelView:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
```

Comment: You should specify what you mean with "animation". What animation you want?

Comment: i mean that when the i click the button the view is showed through proper animation not normal

Comment: there are tons of animations possible, you should really clarify what you want.

Comment: i did not apply any animation yet. so i have no idea.

Comment: http://www.raywenderlich.com/2454/how-to-use-uiview-animation-tutorial basic tutorial about UIView animations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try it....

```
 [UIView beginAnimations: nil context: nil];
 [UIView setAnimationBeginsFromCurrentState: YES];
 [UIView setAnimationDuration: 0.5];
 view1.frame = CGRectMake(20,45,110,548); //Set frame according your choice
 [UIView commitAnimations];
```

Hope i helped.

Comment: sir its working fine, but can we change the style of animation i mean anohter animation

Comment: @Nasir : If it's working then you should accept answer and give up vote. Set animation time according your choice.

Comment: @Nasir : [UIView setAnimationTransition:UIViewAnimationTransitionFlipFromRight forView:self.view cache:NO];

Answer (score 0):

Use this for display view with animation

https://github.com/kohtenko/KOPopupView